# How to purge WineHQ PPA? doesn't appears in sources after added

Tags: apt, ppa, software-sources, purge

Kubuntu 20.04 64 Bit, fresh install with some gaming applications.

```
ls -al /etc/apt/sources.list.d/
total 32
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 jun  2 08:04 .
drwxr-xr-x 7 root root 4096 jun  2 08:04 ..
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   71 jun  2 08:04 amdvlk.list
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   71 jun  2 08:04 amdvlk.list.save
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  128 jun  2 08:04 ernstp-ubuntu-mesarc-focal.list
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  128 jun  2 08:04 ernstp-ubuntu-mesarc-focal.list.save
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  138 jun  2 08:04 lutris-team-ubuntu-lutris-focal.list
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  138 jun  2 08:04 lutris-team-ubuntu-lutris-focal.list.save

wine --version
wine-5.9 (Staging)
```

As you see after I added WineHQ PPA it sitll doesn't appear in sources so I can remove the software source.
wioth
Hiting TAB with **ppa-purge** doesn't find the PPA

```
ppa-purge 
-d                  ernstp/mesarc       -h                  -i                  lutris-team/lutris  -o                  -p                  -s                  -y
```

Comment: how did you add the ppa?

Comment: with the WineHQ instructions, add key, add ppa, update install winehq-staging with recommends

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To remove the WineHQ repository on Ubuntu 20.04 open the terminal and type:

```
sudo add-apt-repository --remove 'deb https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu/ focal main' 
sudo apt update
```

You may also remove the PPAs by launching the Software & Updates utility and navigating to *Other Software* tab where you'll see them listed and at the bottom is a *Remove* button for removing a software source from the list .